# Working with multiple classes

Tags: c#

I have three classes in C# that I'm trying to work with. The classes are incredibly similar but have a few minor variations. Because each class is different and stored in a separate DB table, I need functions to return each class type, but because they're so similar they could almost be written with the same functions in my controller.

I'd rather not write the exact same set of functions in my controller with no difference other than input/output classes, but I can't for the life of me figure out how.

I tried polymorphism, but I'll be honest, it was downright confusing to the point where I separated the classes out because I can't access subclass properties within the parent class and it was just a mess.

**How do I properly work with these three disparate yet similar classes?**

This is what I have currently, but it **doesn't work** because `task` can't be declared inside the `switch` statement. (That would ideally fix my problems). I also can't declare a *generic* variable outside of the `switch` and give it a type inside the `switch`, because C# doesn't allow that.

```
var type = _projectService.GetTaskTypeById(id);
/* object task; doesn't work. I can declare it inside the switch statement
   but it doesn't "become" the new type (the last line throws an error: 
   "object does not contain a definition for ToModel()")
*/

switch (type)
{
    case "MS":
        var task = _projectService.GetMSTaskById(id);
        break;
    case "TL":
        var task = _projectService.GetTLTaskById(id);
        break;
    case "ET":
        var task = _projectService.GetETTaskById(id);
        break;
    default:
        // throw error
}

task.ToModel();
```

Comment: Declare `task` outside the switch using a concrete or base type. Do the `GetXXTaskById` return the same or a derivation of the same type? They would have to if you can call `.ToModel` on any one of the types...

Comment: I think that your real problem is the sentence _I tried polymorphism, but..._ you should show (a partial) implementation of the common part of these classes and how you failed with the polymorphism approach

Comment: If you don't like inheritance then alternatively use an Interface. In you case it could contain the `.ToModel()` method and implement that on all 3 classes.

Comment: Can you show the code for two of the classes? If they are *almost exact*, it should be possible to extract the same parts into one *model* (class, abstract class, interface).

Comment: @Steve I've since overwritten the code, but it was checked in to TFS at some point so I can dig it up if necessary. Essentially, I had a parent class (`Task`) that the three subclasses implemented (`MS`, `TL`, `ET`). I kept running into problems because there's no way that I'm aware of or could find to a) get a child's parameters when the parent was called, or b) get the type of entry when using EF TPH inheritance. That's why I gave up and moved to separate classes for each, resulting in the mess I have now.

Answer (score 3):

The best you are going to be able to hope for is to use inheritance or an interface.  Start with a base class that has all the functions that are similar, then have each of your three different classes inherit this class. Finally, instead of using "var" to define object task, use the base class, defined prior to the switch statement.

Answer (score 1):

Right answer would be declaring a common base class or interface but you said "I tried polymorphism, but". I do not know what (or how) did you try but assuming,

1. You are sure that all classes have a `ToModel()` method
2. It is not practical to declare a common interface or base class for your classes
3. You are using .NET 4.0 or above

You can do

```
var type = _projectService.GetTaskTypeById(id);

dynamic task;

switch (type)
{
    case "MS":
        task = _projectService.GetMSTaskById(id);
        break;
    case "TL":
        task = _projectService.GetTLTaskById(id);
        break;
    case "ET":
        task = _projectService.GetETTaskById(id);
        break;
    default:
        throw new NotSupportedException("Unsupported Task Type: " + type);
}

task.ToModel();
```

Comment: Why not start with option 2, and use `dynamic` as a last resort?

Comment: Because OP said "I tried polymorphism, but..." so we are already at last resort

Comment: I didn't even know about `dynamic`, thank you for this. I have to initialize `task` to `null` for it to compile; I'll let you know about at runtime.

Comment: If you write a throw statement in default, that error should disappear

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd do something along the lines of...

```
public interface IProjectTask
{
    Task GetTaskById(int id);
}

public enum ProjectTaskTypes
{
    MS = 1,
    TL = 2,
    ET = 3
}
public class ProjectTaskFactory
{
    public static IProjectTask GetInstance(ProjectTaskTypes projectTaskType,
                                           int projectTaskId)
    {
        IProjectTask task;
        switch(projectTaskType)
        {
            case ProjectTaskTypes.MS:
                task = new MSProjectTask(projectTaskId);
                break;
            case ProjectTaskTypes.TL:
                task = new TLProjectTask(projectTaskId);
                break;
            case ProjectTaskTypes.ET:
                task = new ETProjectTask(projectTaskId);
                break;
            default:
                // throw error
        }       
        return task;
    }
}

//usage
var projectTask = ProjectTaskFactory.GetInstance(type);
projectTask.ToModel()
```

Just as a side note - creating a enum for the project types I feel is better, no magic strings in code, and better readability.

Separating them out is not only part of the Single Responsibility Pattern, but also means writing unit tests may be easier.

Comment: I'm using enums for everything else, just forgot to add them for this once I went away from polymorphism. Thanks for the reminder!